# Is the mail.smtp.sendpartial property used in javamail specific to the sun implementation?

Tags: java, properties, smtp, jakarta-mail, rfc

Is the mail.smtp.sendpartial property used in javamail specific to the sun implementation?

Or can I expect (or hope) that the gnu implementation would also use this property and provide the same behaviour (i.e., send what it can if property set to true).

If this is sun specific, would it be true to say that ALL properties starting with mail.smtp. are sun specific ?

i.e., am I right to assume that the smtp classes, i.e., SMTPTransport, are those classes that are implementation specific, and any property mentioned in the sun documentation is used only in the sun implementation, and none of these properties are mentioned by any RFC ?

Answer (score 1):

The mail.smtp.sendpartial property is not defined by the JavaMail spec and thus is specific to the Sun provider.  The JavaMail spec defines some standard properties, including some mail. properties.  Hopefully this is all clear from the [JavaMail javadocs](http://javamail.kenai.com/nonav/javadocs/index.html), have you read the javadocs?  In particular, the documentation for the various packages describes the properties; don't forget to scroll down.

Comment: Yes, thanks, I see from the docs that there are API specific properties, as documented in the package documentation. But I was hoping to find somewhere that at least a subset would be (or perhaps should be) supported generally.

Otherwise, the sun specific implementation supports features that I would have thought generally obvious. And making dealing with the 'standard' API that much more painful. For example;

sendpartial=true ---> why not standard behaviour?
reportsuccess=true  ---> the only (also ugly) way to get extra information from the remote server about success! response code...

Comment: There are three reasons more of this isn't standardized: 1. We tried to keep the standard API relatively protocol-independent; 2. There's been virtually no demand to standardize these things; 3. Standardizing them requires additional work and we're already resource-limited.